# Can i use jar file as a source code of AWS Glue job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am new to the aws glue and I have one java code which I want to run with aws glue, so does aws glue provide any privilege to directly run jar file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can. In fact, Spark itself is built on Java and supports it. The compatibility on calling Java libraries from Scala is top-notch.

As far as glue is concerned, [they have params you can use to add your own jar files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html):

```
--extra-jars

    The Amazon S3 paths to additional Java .jar files that AWS Glue adds to the Java classpath before executing your script. Multiple values must be complete paths separated by a comma (,).
```

Answer (score 0):

Glue does not support Java, only Python and Scala so this is not possible.

Comment: So I need to convert that code into python or scala to run?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that

Comment: An upvote and an accept would be highly appreciated then :)

Comment: You can have your Scala application packaged as a Fat JAR. So the answer is true that Glue only accepts source files (Scala or Python), but it has nothing to do with Jar being in Java. It just doesn't support that kind of submit like EMR.